# vue.js how to not change prop for object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

in my parent component, i have a filter object as empty `{}`...

I have a filter component, which is the child of that parent component and I got something like this:

`<filter-component :filters.sync="filters" />`  (filters is the `{}` empty from the start).

in the `filter-component` there's a method which does this:

```
filter(group, filter) {

                const filters = this.filters;

                // do something here as in change the filter
                // filters[group].push(filter);

                this.$emit('update:filters', Object.assign({}, filters));

            }
```

as you can see, child component happens to change the prop(not directly reference, because of  push in the nested one), but still, it changes it.

What do i have to do to fix this?

The only idea that comes to my mind is that the line where I have `const filters = this.filters` should be changed so that instead of equal, it deep copies . This way, each time filter changes from `filter-component` , it's gonna emit totally new one and also won't change it .

Shallow copy seems to not work in this case. Any other idea other than deep copy ? i am trying to avoid lodash package at all.

Comment: see if this works this.$emit('update:filters', {...this.filters}) or this.$emit('update:filters', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.filters))) or let's fix together, ping me on skype: syed_haroon :)

Answer (score 0):

For adding properties to an existing object, you can use [$set API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) to ensure they trigger reactive updates. In this case, you could loop through your filters and set each one.